# Why association is not creating in Doctrine2?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have 2 entities — `NewsItem` and `Category`. It is unidirectional association between this entities: 1 `NewsItem` has 1 `Category`, 1 `Category` has many `NewsItem`'s.

I am trying to create association mapping like in [THIS](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional) example. What I've tried? My code:

```
class NewsItem {
    // other fields

    /**
    * @var int
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="News\Entity\Category")
    */
    protected $category_id;

    // other fiels, getters, setters etc
}
```

After that, I deleted tables in the database manually and run command `orm:schema-tool:update --force` in command line. It says that some queries are executed without errors — it's ok. But when I open table `Category` in HeidiSQL there are no FOREIGN KEYS there. That means that tables are not linked.

What I did wrong?

You can watch full code of this `News\Entity\NewsItem` entity here: [click me](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/my-zf2-project/blob/developing/module/News/src/News/Entity/NewsItem.php). `News\Entity\Category` entity is here: [click me](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/my-zf2-project/blob/developing/module/News/src/News/Entity/Category.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should remove `* @ORM\Column(type="integer")` as it is conflicting with the many-to-one relation.

Even if it is not the cause of the bug, you should also rename `protected $category_id;` to `protected $category;`

Also, your two entities are under the same namespace so it's not necessary to add the related entity's full path. `targetEntity="Category"` is enough.

Comment: I will try it now. Is there a way to validate model/entity to avoid such mistakes?

Comment: yep you can run : `$ php app/console doctrine:schema:validate` (assuming you are using symfony2)

Comment: Hm. I am using zf2 and I run commands like `orm:*`. I know command `orm:validate-schema` but it says that mapping files are ok (so it is not detecting such mistakes). Is there any flag to find such mistakes?

Comment: This worked, thank you very much! I mean your answer.

Comment: what if I need to set nullable? I don't want to allow to add rows with null category_id, for example? I can did this with `@Column(nullable=false)`, but you said it is conficting with `many-to-one`

Comment: use `@ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)`

Comment: Hm. I added it, tried to update my schema and it said, that everthing is up to date so database is not updated. Why?

Comment: because nullable=false is default setup.

Comment: But I just tried to add row with null category_id and I added it without any errors.

Comment: can you check if category_id is not nullable using phpmyadmin (in table structure) ?

Comment: Make sure you aren't using quotes around false.  Doctrine uses values wrapped in quotes as a string which in PHP evaluates to true when converted to boolean.

Comment: C̶h̶e̶c̶k̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶: h̶t̶t̶p̶s̶:̶/̶/̶g̶i̶t̶h̶u̶b̶.̶c̶o̶m̶/̶s̶h̶a̶r̶i̶k̶o̶v̶v̶l̶a̶d̶i̶s̶l̶a̶v̶/̶m̶y̶-̶z̶f̶2̶-̶p̶r̶o̶j̶e̶c̶t̶/̶t̶r̶e̶e̶/̶d̶e̶v̶e̶l̶o̶p̶i̶n̶g̶/̶m̶o̶d̶u̶l̶e̶/̶N̶e̶w̶s̶/̶s̶r̶c̶/̶N̶e̶w̶s̶/̶E̶n̶t̶i̶t̶y̶) ̶p̶l̶e̶a̶s̶e̶.̶  Did your first version was `@ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)`? :)))

Answer (score 1):

You have incorrect mapping information for the Category entity.

Your **NewsItem.php** file should look like this:

```
namespace Your\Bundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\JoinColumn;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="news_item")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class NewsItem {
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Category
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="news_items")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $category;

    // Rest of code omitted.
}
```

And your **Category.php** should look like this:

```
namespace Your\Bundle\Entity;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="category")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Category {    
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="NewsItem", mappedBy="category")     
     */
    private $news_items;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->news_items = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // Rest of code omitted.
}
```

Comment: Why I need `private $news_items;` in Category?

Comment: @SharikovVladislav If it is there, then you can access NewsItem-s from Category entity, if it is not there, then you can't.

Comment: Would I be able to get it through [DQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins)?

Comment: But it is more preferable to use your method right?

Comment: @SharikovVladislav Depends on situation, but in most cases yes.

Comment: Updated it. Thank you very much. You know I can't accept your answer. Answer to my question was in another, anyway you helped me very much too. Thank you!

Comment: I will add this to my scheme. If I will use it ok - if not - Nothing bad will happen, right? :) Thank you again.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav Nothing bad happens ... ;)

Comment: Can you clarify last thing for me? I don't want to allow adding row with null `category_id`. How I can achieve that?

Comment: + can you explain why after `orm:schema-tool:update` table `newsitems` (without capital letters) added, but not `NewsItems`? `NewsCategories` fine :). Folder with entities: [click me](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/my-zf2-project/tree/developing/module/News/src/News/Entity). Item.php first lines.

Comment: + can you explain why you using @ with my name ? :))) I'll get norification anyway - I am the authour of the post.